# tuple with dict to list with element modification

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

Given tuple like below,

```
tpl = ('abc', {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

need to create a list out of this preferably through comprehension if possible.

Expected output

```
['abc', 'a: 1', 'b: 2']
```

Tuple can be converted to a list by calling list(tpl)

The part where the dict `key:val` is converted to `key` + `" : "` + `val` can be done by something like below

`[k + " : " + v for k, v in dict.items()]`

I think the part of selectively calling the above manipulation be done by checking the type (only for dict) - need some help to get to the complete solution.

Also as a separate problem, is there a way to do this inplace ?

Comment: Very curious to know why would you destroy that beautiful structure? @user3206440

Comment: "Also as a separate problem, is there a way to do this inplace ?" No, you cannot convert a tuple to a list in-place, type conversions never work that way, and besides, tuple objects are immutable.

Comment: ```tp_converted = list(tpl)```
```tp_converted[1] =  [str(k) + " : " + str(v) for k, v tp_converted[1].items()]```
isn't that what you want to achieve? you already have your answer I guess in what you wrote

Comment: if you mean that the string and the dict appearances/order in the tuple could be manipulated then the answer provided is satisfactory for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using list-comprehension.

```
tpl = ('abc', {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
answer = [
  x for dict_or_str in tpl for x in 
  ( 
    [f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in dict_or_str.items()] 
    if isinstance(dict_or_str, dict)
    else [dict_or_str]
  )
]
print(answer)
```

Output

```
['abc', 'a: 1', 'b: 2']
```

Answer (score 1):

For an accurate solution to this, you'll have to take care of the specific `dtypes` contained in the tuples and handle them individually. So using `isinstance` and appending the elements with the corresponding logic. For the shared example, something like the following should do:

```
l= []
for i in tpl:
    if isinstance(i, str):
        l.append(i)
    elif isinstance(i, dict):
        for k,v in i.items():
            l.append(f'{k}: {str(v)}')
```

---

```
print(l)
# ['abc', 'a: 1', 'b: 2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use `filter` like the following:

```
tpl = ('abc', {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
iter = filter(lambda d: type(d) == dict , list(tpl))
sol = list(filter(lambda d: type(d) != dict , list(tpl)))

for elem in iter:
    for k, v in elem.items():
        sol.append("{:}: {:}".format(k, v))

print(sol)
#['abc', 'a: 1', 'b: 2']
```